# Have GCC 11.2 implemented std::hash for std::coroutine_handle yet?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

I read the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/coroutine_handle) and find out there is a helper function `std::hash` for `std::coroutine_handle`.
But I cannot use `std::coroutine_handle` as key of `std::unordered_map` when compiling the code with GCC 11.2. The error message is `use of deleted function 'std::hash<std::__n4861::coroutine_handle<void> >::~hash()'`.

I am not sure about that is the error caused by not implementing the `std::hash` for `std::coroutine_handle` or something else.

Comment: You seem to have shown conclusive evidence that this is not implemented in gcc 11.2.

Comment: Have you tried looking? https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yeh I've implemented a simple `std::hash` for it and the code compiles. I am now just a little curious why gcc haven't implemented it yet, the status seems to be complete according the there website.

Comment: @Taekahn Yes I've checked this. It just shows that the coroutine is implemented from 10. Maybe there is something I missed.

Comment: What about gcc's support for coroutines, do they show its support as complete. And even though it's complete it could be a simple oversight.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It looks like it's complemeted according to https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html.